# Can an executable know where it is stored?

Tags: directory, executable

Can an executable know where it is stored?

For my open source project, I wrote a small bash script to automate some operations. The script lies at the root of the project and performs its tasks on all files below. People have the project files on their own computers, at their favorite path, so I can't just hardcode `cd /home/nico/projects/theproject` at the beginning of the script. I don't want to force people to manually `cd` to the project's directory everytime before executing either. I would like people to be able to use a Gnome shortcut to launch the script. To do so, the script needs to know where itself is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash
echo I am located in $(dirname "$0")
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

Note that this may be a relative path.

Answer (score 4):

```
#! /bin/bash
w=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && echo "$PWD")
echo I am located in "$w"
```

To build off of cjm's answer, the above will absolutize the path (by using a sub-shell to `cd` there and `echo` the `$PWD`)

Comment: Thanks! My script works fine with cjm's answer, but yours is interesting as well.